# Spans taking up entire row

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the this layout [example](http://jsfiddle.net/SxcqH/406/) working (if you give the result tab more room, you can see how the spans respond).

I have the same code, but for some reason, each span takes up its own row.

[image: image of spans]

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Wooo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" id="font-awesome-css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css">
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="well">1<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
            </div>

            <div class="span8">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6"><div class="well">2</div></div>
                    <div class="span6"><div class="well">3</div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6"><div class="well">4</div></div>
                    <div class="span6"><div class="well">5</div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span4"><div class="well">2</div></div>
                    <div class="span4"><div class="well">3</div></div>
                    <div class="span4"><div class="well">4</div></div>
                </div>  
           </div>
        </div>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/scrolling.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There might be some difference between your CSS and the CSS in the fiddle. Try loading your bootstrap CSS from the same CDN as the fiddle, instead of your local resources, and disable your own CSS (`site.css`). If that works, then undo these changes bit by bit until you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Mind sharing the page you are having an issue with (non-fiddle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a post [here](http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/08/bootstrap-3-grids-explained/),

> In Bootstrap 3, the .span* classes have been removed, and replaced
>   with a combination of .col-* classes: .col-xs-*, .col-sm-*, .col-md-*,
>   and.col-lg-*.

I have modified the snippet to the following which seems to do the trick:

```html
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">1
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="well">2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="well">3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="well">4</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="well">5</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```